# Copy cells between related documents faster than Range.Copy(...)

Tags: c#, excel, optimization, epplus

I have built a template engine for Excel at work. It has `For...Each` loops for populating columns and rows with the contents of passed template variables. A sheet can grow... like a couple of rectangles continents pushing each other to get enough space - leaving holes sometimes.

I have a source document (template) and a target document (output file). I am using EPPlus for copying cells from template to output file. This generic Excel engine is much slower than the handwritten Interop code (factor 2!!!).

A profiler showed me that the big time consumer is the `Range.Copy(destinationRange)` method. Soooo... actually I only want the destination cells to look the same as the source cells.
Is there a faster way?

Unzipping the Excel file, I see there is only one style file. The output file could start with the styles of the template file. But how can this be done? And how do I address style information?

(I will spent a look at the EPPlus source...)

Comment: what are you trying to do? keeping it short, you are trying to copy contents of one excel to another?

Comment: Yes. But copying from a template document. All styles are already known. So the effort should not be SO big.

Comment: The solution is to open the template file as output file, set the StyleID of new cells to the StyleID of the template cell and at last delete the original sheets.

Comment: Side note: If you are copying (or setting styles) on one cell at a time (e.g. one at a time in a loop) it will be slow.  When using EPPlus, try to perform operations on as big a group of cells as possible at one time - that will speed things up.